# Writing tests for "assertEqual" and "assertNotEqual": should I bother?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I've got a `Coordinate` class, which has an `add(Coordinate)` method. When writing unit tests for this class, I've got tests to `assertEqual` a result:

```
a = Coordinate(1,2,3)
b = Coordinate(5,6,7)

result = a.add(b) 

assertEqual(result.x, 6)
assertEqual(result.y, 8)
assertEqual(result.z,10)
```

I can 'fake' this rather easily:

```
def add(self, other):
    return Coordinate(6,8,10)
```

This is the simplest solution to the test failure. The next step is to write a second test which prevents me from faking it in this manner. I could either:

- write another `assertEqual` test with different numbers (so faking the `Coordinate(6,8,10)` doesn't pass, or
- Write an `assertNotEqual` test with two different inputs, ensuring that the result isn't `6,8,10`.

If I write an `assertEquals` test, I've then got two tests that look very, very similar. Is this a problem? If I saw code that similar in the project, I'd be tempted to refactor it. Should I do this for the test code too - and, if so, won't this mean **every** pair of tests will end up being refactored?

If I write an `assertNotEqual`, the test is only testing for "fake results" - which I am very sure won't ever come up from an algorithmic error. In essence, once I write the test, stop faking the result so both tests pass, the `assertNotEquals` test *can be safely removed*, and I will **still** have confidence in the code - so I'd write the test, fix the fake, remove the test, which seems rather silly.

What should I be doing in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another assertEqual test with different numbers will be good enough. If possible, take a "borderline" or uncommon case, like :

```
a = Coordinate(1,2,3)
b = Coordinate(-5,-6,-7)
...
```

An AssertNotEqual test would be absurd and not intuitive for the reader IMO.

In any case, I wouldn't worry too much about this kind of tests. As a reader it's really obvious that the developer who wrote them just wanted to test a couple of cases, and it would take a real refactoring extremist to want to refactor them. I mean, it's only 2 tests with almost no duplication, the intent is obvious and it's not like you have to rewrite 300 lines of code when the object changes...

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't get too worried about being able to 'fake-pass' a test as you describe - it will always be possible to write a convoluted `if` statement inside your method to make each of your test cases pass. Instead have a look at the logic involved in your `add` method and ensure that your test cases cover all the code branches - that should be good enough in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It would be impossible to write tests that guard against someone maliciously writing code to fake out the testing code based on the particular cases the test code uses. So you shouldn't try.

When I say "impossible" I don't mean just "very hard", it may be an instance of the [Liar Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) which breaks formal systems.

Comment: Well, theoretically, you could write a suite of tests that tests every possible combination of `Coordinate`s. In that case, if `add` were maliciously coded to fake out the testing code, it would still work as expected for all possible inputs.

Comment: @EricFinn I have an infinitely long bridge that I'd like to sell you. Okay, it isn't infinite, it is only a yottameter long, but if you need more just say how many `bridges = lambda n: sum([10 ** 24 for _ in range(n)])`

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm going to change Coordinate to Int - for simplicity. Also the below syntax is made up.. so won't execute. But it should get my point across

```
testAdd()
  assertThat(2.Add(2), isEqualTo(4))
```

You then can fake this out by making Add return 4 always. Next to triangulate (drive general code by varying certain params).

```
testAdd()
  assertThat(2.Add(2), isEqualTo(4))
  assertThat(3.Add(5), isEqualTo(8))
```

Now you need to make Add to do some actual work..
Once it is green, you could either let the two tests remain or you could delete the simple/trivial ones - as long as it doesn't let your confidence drop. If the duplication bothers you, you could see if your test runner supports 'parameterized tests'

```
[2,2,4]
[3,5,8]
testAdd(operand1, operand2, expectedResult)
  assertThat(operand1.Add(operand2), isEqualTo(expectedResult))
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the Coordinate.Add() method look like?

Seems like *that* method should handle how to add (no point faking it), and then all you need to do is:

```
# In your test setUp code
testCoord = Coordinate(6, 8, 10)  # Explicitly setting the value you expect the test to return.
addCoord1 = Coordinate(1, 2, 3)
addCoord2 = Coordinate(5, 6, 7)

# The test
addCoord1.add(addCoord2)
assertEqual(testCoord, addCoord1, "Testing addition of coordinates using add() method.")
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you using a unit test framework? I'd put the object creation in the setUp of a testcase in `unittest`, personally.